# How to use one array to calculate and set values in separate array

Tags: c#, arrays, class, foreach

How do I create a method `setOutput()` that calculates and sets the max output of each item (a,b,c,d) in `Formula` by multiplying the `percentage` in `Formula` to the `amt` in `Item` through its common `id`? I think I worked out the logic but I don't know how to use the `id` to reference values for calculation.

I.e. how do I reference values by their `id` within arrays in a nested `foreach` loop?

```
Class Item { 
    public string id { get;set }
    public double? amt { get;set } }

Class Formula { 
    public string id { get;set }
    public double? percent { get;set }
    public double? output { get;set } }


Item[] inventory = { 
    new Item { id = "a", amt = 111.1},
    new Item { id = "b", amt = 222.2},
    new Item { id = "c", amt = 333.3,
    new Item { id = "d", amt = 400.4} }

Formula[] formulas = { new Formula {
      {id = "a", percent=25.0, output = null}, 
      {id = "b", percent=25.0, output = null}, 
      {id = "c", percent=25.0, output = null},
      {id = "d", percent=25.0, output = null}; },

    new Formula { 
      {id = "a", percent=20.0, output = null}; 
      {id = "b", percent=20.0, output = null}; 
      {id = "c", percent=60.0, output = null};
      {id = "d", percent= 0.0, output = null}; },

    new Formula { 
      {id = "a", percent=30.0, output = null}; 
      {id = "b", percent=30.0, output = null}; 
      {id = "c", percent=20.0, output = null};
      {id = "d", percent=20.0} output = null}; } }

setOutput(Item[] inventory, Formula[] formulas) 
{

// Loop through each Formula in formulas
//      Loop through each Item in 
//          Item.amt * Formula.percentage/100 = Formula.amt

foreach (var Formula in formulas) //
    {
        foreach (Item item in Raw)
            {
                (id="a") Raw.amt* Formula.percent/100 = Formula.output
                (id="b") Raw.amt* Formula.percent/100 = Formula.output
                (id="c") Raw.amt* Formula.percent/100 = Formula.output
                (id="d") Raw.amt* Formula.percent/100 = Formula.output
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information. I'm unable to understand your problem

Comment: I edited it for clarification.  Thank you

Comment: formulas is an array but you are setting that to array of list of formulas is there a typo error in your problem statement

Comment: Changed it to arrays.  Thank you

Comment: Your code references `Raw` but that does not seem to be defined?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. How can one `Formula` object contain multiple `id`s?

Comment: There is a free edition of Visual Studio. Before asking a question, you should at least be able to fix basic syntax errors on your own like missing (or extra) `;` and `}`.

Comment: My problem is I'm new to this format.  Thanks for the patience and I'll learn to better ask and post questions as well as post better code

Answer (score 0):

Hi assuming if your Item array has Items with unique id's something like below in your code

```
Item[] inventory = {new Item { id = "a", amt = 111.1},
                    new Item { id = "b", amt = 222.2},
                    new Item { id = "c", amt = 333.3 },
                    new Item { id = "d", amt = 400.4} };
Formula[] formulas = { new Formula  {id = "a", percent=25.0, output = null} ,
                      new Formula {id = "b", percent=25.0, output = null} ,
                      new Formula {id = "c", percent=25.0, output = null},
                      new Formula {id = "d", percent=25.0, output = null} };
```

Then in your setouput function you could do something like below to set your output property in formulas array

```
formulas.ToList().ForEach(var => var.output = var.percent * inventory.First(var1 => var1.id == var.id).amt / 100);
```

A better approach is to make formulas data type from Formula[] to List

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant for your formulas to be `List<Formula>[]` so you could have lists of `Formula`s, converting the `inventory` of `Item`s to a `Dictionary` makes it easy:

```
void setOutput(Item[] inventory, List<Formula>[] formulas) {
    var Raw = inventory.ToDictionary(i => i.id, i => i.amt);

    foreach (var FormulaSet in formulas)
        foreach (var formula in FormulaSet)
            formula.output = Raw[formula.id] * formula.percent / 100;
}
```